# How to bypass reCaptcha during scraping via Request?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to **scrape**  [idealista](https://idealista.com). I have to make a lot of requests page by page and obviously, at a point they asked to bypass the reCaptcha. And I don't know how to solve it using Requests.

- I have tried selenium with sleep function but it doesn't work for me because in that case **scraping** goes slowly.

> As far as I know, there is a possibility to solve it by POST method
> with the data key of the web site and recaptha response. I found these
> values but have I no idea how to do it in Requests.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use a recaptcha solving service and integrate it with your code .

Comment: Are you sending GET requests with request headers? You can always use proxy servers if you keep getting flagged.